# Haxe not detecting libraries

Tags: flash, compiler-errors, flashdevelop, haxe, nme

I am a newbie to haxe and nme, and I thought I'd make a sample project and see how it all works. I normally use FlashDevelop for the IDE.

First I tried to run the Actuate Example provided here:
http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/2011/07/05/getting-set-with-haxe-nme-and-webos-even-easie/

And in the command prompt it told me it could not find the first import (ie Actuate)

Then I tried using FlashDevelop and created an NME project. When I try to compile to any platform it tells me:

> haxelib run nme build C:\Users\Zeeshan\Documents\Newnme\application.nmml flash
>
> Library nme is not installed
>   Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe)
>
> Done(1)

Could I have any suggestions for help please?

Update:
Doing it directly in prompt gives:

> C:\Users\Zeeshan>haxelib run nme build C:\Users\Zeeshan\Documents\Newnme\applica
>   tion.nmml flash
>
> Error: : Invalid DCE mode, expected std | full | no.
>
> Haxe Compiler 3.0.0 - (C)2005-2013 Haxe Foundation

Comment: ... and by the way, I HAVE installed Actuate and NME libraries via cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that sample project was designed for Haxe 2, and some of the command line parameters have changed with Haxe 3.  Also, OpenFL seems to be the future.

The same (or similar?) sample project, but for OpenFL and Haxe 3 (instead of NME and Haxe 2) is available here:

https://github.com/openfl/openfl-samples

Give those samples a shot...